# NPM Issue while running from jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gradle

I am currently facing some issue which are related to gradle/NodeJS. What I did is used Node plugin by writing this in my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.12'
 }
```

now when I try to run install npm command from terminal(CentOS) by running:

```
gradle npmInstall
```

it is running perfectly fine and installing all the required packages whereas when I run the same command from Jenkins (Jenkins installed in centos), I am getting following error msg:

```
:npmInstall FAILED
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'.
  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':npmInstall'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)

Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'npm'
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
```

Can somebody please help me with is. I am not getting what Wrong I am doing.
I am also getting the same error msg if try to run following command:

```
gradle npm_run_build_prod
```

whereas the same list of commands are working for my local windows jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved on the [Gradle help forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/npm-issue-while-running-from-jenkins/25009/3?u=vinay_a_verma).  The solution is to download Node.js during the build by adding this to build.gradle:

```
node {
    download = true
    version='9.2.0'
}
```